# 60s TV series episode with a giant hand

Tags: story-identification, tv

During the 60s, I remember watching a TV live-action episode in black and white. I am almost certain that it belonged to the 1966 Japanese series adaptation of Akuma-Kun.

Here below the only memories that I have from this episode:

There is a fishing vessel in a sea storm at night. Suddenly, a giant hand emerges from the deepest of the ocean and a voice of thunder is heard begging something like "Give me a ladle! Give me a ladle!", then, one of the fishermen tossed a ladle to the hand. The hand grabs the ladle which now is equal in size to the hand. Finally, the hand fills the ladle with water and pours it onto the ship, sinking it.

Sadly, I don't have the DVD of the mentioned Akuma-Kun 1966 TV series. I went through a few plotlines and synopsis of its episodes on the Internet but I couldn't find anything related to the giant hand. Can someone identify this episode providing at least one still with the hand?

[image]

I have found a couple of external references from episode 3 of this Akuma-Kun TV show about a giant monster (an alien mummy). The first one mentions 
[a hand (mummy's hand) that flies](http://www.zmdb.org/tv/2036-Akuma_Kun--Episode_3_(1966).htm) and the second one is a
[video where the mummy itself that emerges from the water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS6rupSVNp0) in minute 1:09 but I am not sure if this is the episode that I am looking for.

Comment: @Danny3414: I really don't remember a big wave but it could have been as a part of the sea storm. As I stated in my post, the only thing that I remember was the humongous hand pouring water upon the ship with the big ladle.

Comment: I only saw the second half of the episode, but one of Johnny Sokko had an enemy that was a giant robotic flying hand. Might it be that?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: I don't think that the robotic hand which you cite is the one that I remember. Please, see my post with updated info.

Comment: That would be a *Funayūrei* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funay%C5%ABrei).